# How to disable WiFi in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I want my machine to work only on Ethernet. I mean I want to remove the WiFi access in my Ubuntu.

Comment: You could also blacklist the driver for the wireless card. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` I will propose a solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hard block wifi (that means completely turn the wifi chip off) then you must do it from bios settings (my laptop has also an external switch).

If you want to soft block wifi (that means disable wifi from within the os) then you can do it with these 3 ways:

- with a combination of `Fn` key and some other for example `F8` if you have a laptop.
- by right clicking on network manager indicator on your panel and uncheck the `Enable Wi-Fi` option.
- Finally by the command `sudo rfkill block wifi` (use the command `rfkill list` to check it).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to click the Network manager icon on top of the screen and disable Wi-Fi there.

Comment: ok I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/modprobe.d` add the below and reboot:

```
install iwlwifi /bin/true
```

Comment: This may want a little more explanation:  `/etc/modprobe.d` is a directory, so I assume that you mean that this should be added to some file within the directory.

Comment: Oops I meant in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_modules.conf, I can't seem to edit my comment now though